# telerikReportViewer-16.1.22.511.min.js - Uncaught (in promise) The current data set presented in the report did not produce any significant content

Tags: telerik, reporting

telerik reporting > js console error > Uncaught (in promise) The current data set presented in the report did not produce any significant content, so no pages were generated. If you need to see the whole report content, including blank pages, please contact the report author. telerikReportViewer-16.1.22.511.min.js:9
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmDWY.jpg)

The JS errors showed up after telerik reporting lib upgrade. I tried changing SkipBlankPages property but no difference.